# How do i schedule emails based on deadline in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, smtp

I need my `rails` application to send automatic emails based on a project deadline. Please suggest a gem I need to use. Also, how do I setup `SMTP` for that?

Comment: Here are what you wants may be helpful for you.

[refer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401642/sending-mails-automatically-through-action-mailer-rails-3-1

Answer (score 0):

For scheduling tasks, you can use [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) gem. It uses redis to store the tasks. You can use  something like resque-scheduler gem to enqueue tasks at a specific time.

As for smtp, I would suggest you to go for a service like [mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com). If you use mandrill, sending email is nothing more than making an api call.